# How to hide axis bars in area chart and line chart in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I currently have this issue where I am trying to **hide the Y-axis** of this line chart. Currently there is **only the option to hide both axes in GDS**.

Issue being is that the floating number at the y axis looks awkward.

Could anyone think of a work around? maybe hiding both axes and then creating a blank chart with the date values and using that as the x axis ticks.

[image: Current GDS chart]

Answer (score 4):

One *workaround* is to draw a [Shape](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6289367) or line over the axis and set it to a colour that blends in with the background, (although in the case above, it would cut into the first data point and data label) using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + movement keys for precision placement.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/59c8207e-c3c1-4199-8d0c-c53f2ea66c13) as well as a GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Comment: Ahhh okay the only issue is the line cuts through the points on the graph still

Comment: Yes; there's a [Roadmap](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1HP875f1zGdvHspEas2PATY6_4kCTpULUFBUUN4fYypo/edit#slide=id.g862c11d094_2_4331) of features and enhancements expected in Google Data Studio in 2020; will update the post if there are changes to axis formatting options.